# What does T represent in this class signature and how can i Instantiate this class?

Tags: c#

I am looking at some of my professor's code for him while he is on Holiday and i came across this unreferenced class. Can someone please explain what T represents and possibly how to instantiate a class such as this?

```
public class RowToObject<T> where T : new()
```

Comment: Can you post some more of that class?

Comment: @Sign - The code that was provided is more then enough.  This is simple syntax question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`T` is anything with a public parameterless constructor as constrained by:

`where T : new()`

To instantiate it, provide a type for `T` that has a public parameterless constructor:

`var myRowToObject = new RowToObject<AnotherClass>();`

As for how it's intended to be used in your code-base, no idea! :-)

Answer (score 4):

RowToObject is a generic class, it takes a type in parameter. This type is identified by T and the constraint (T : new()) enforces that this type must have a default constructor.

[More on constraints.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This is a `Generic` class.  It takes a Type within Angle Brackets like this `RowToObject<SomeType>`.  The `Where` bit acts like a filter that says the type passed in must have a public constructor with no parameters on it.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming RowToObject has a parameterless constructor, you would instantiate it something like this:

```
new RowToObject<object>();
```

The T means you can put any class in there that meets the criteria of "has a parameterless constructor" which `System.Object` has.

Although a different object is probably desired. It would depend on how the class is used.

Comment: And what string is returned by the parameterless constructor that you allege exists?

Comment: @EricLippert doh! I should have picked a better object off the top of my head. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

> Can someone please explain what T represents and possibly how to
>   instantiate a class such as this?

**T** is **Type**

```
RowToObject<int> Example = new RowToObject<int>();
```

You really should look into your class notes to understand my answer.

This is how you declare if a class is going to be generic.  While **T** will accept any class, don't be confuse by the **Type** class, there is a reason ( which I cannot explain ) the syntax uses **T**

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth - I actually did provide one.  It was just hidden by the fact I happen to do < int > without the spaces.